# How to show loading message in right frame

Tags: jquery, ajax, frameset

We are using old frameset for our application. It divides the layout in top frame, left frame and right frame. Top and Left frames both have buttons and in right frame we show pages. on clicking of any button  either in top or left frame we first check session thru jquery ajax then display page in right frame. Now we show want to show a loading message in right frame during session checking. Please let me know how can we do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there could be constant connection with backend code (like an interval) to output the right message in the right time in the proper frame. But if you want to handle it in the client side you better chekcout the [jQuery.ba-postmessage](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html) which is for crossdomain scripting and in your case transfering data between frames.